# CSV table header alignment

Tags: tables, csv, csvsimple

I have a simple two-lines csv file, which I've imported to latex with csvsimple like this:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
   1,2,3,4,5
   101,102,104,105,106
   -1,-2,-3,-4,-5
\end{filecontents*}
...
\begin{table}
   \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
      \csvreader{data.csv}{}{\\ \csvlinetotablerow}
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But I want to add a header on the left side of the table and I've been seeing no way to do it.

In other words I want something like this:

[image: Horizontal table]

How does that can be accomplish?

Comment: You cannot add it to your csv file?

Comment: Is that acceptable practice? Latex compiler marks any math insertion in csv file as parse error.

Comment: I just tried it with `$I_c$` and `$U_\mathrm{same}$` and had no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a two-line csv file, you can differentiate between the lines using `\csviffirstrow`. Simply put the two headers into the settings for the first and the following line(s):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
   1,2,3,4,5
   101,102,104,105,106
   -1,-2,-3,-4,-5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \csvloop{
    file=data.csv,
    tabular=|*{6}{c|},
    table head=\hline,
    command=\csviffirstrow{$I_c$}{$U_\mathrm{same}$} & \csvlinetotablerow,
    late after line=\\\hline,
  }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: Suppose all data on `csv` has the format `0.000000`. Is it possible to format the table entry with only 2 decimal places? I mean,  like `0.00`, automatically.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, this is possible. For example, formatting with help of the `siunitx` package can be done. You find an application example in Section 5.4 (page 36) of the `csvsimple` documentation.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm, thanks, but on that example, it only aligns the decimal separator. In my case I want to print only 2 decimal, that is, I want to truncate numbers. I'll post another question.